# Docker Nuget Restore not working getting Found credentials for endpoint and then Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: docker, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am having private feed in azure devops and trying to do dotnet restore inside the docker file its not working

I have attached the Dockerfile for reference

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Nuget.config /src/
COPY Project/ /src/Project/

WORKDIR "/src/Project"

ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"
RUN echo "Environment variables: VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS"
RUN echo $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh)"

RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj" --configfile /src/Nuget.config --verbosity detailed

RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

I am using azure pipeline with these tasks which works and

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'Authenticate to Artifacts'
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: 'ServiceName'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet Restore'
  condition: ne(variables['CacheRestored'],'true')
  inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*$(projectName).csproj'
      arguments: '-r win-x64'
      nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
      feedsToUse: config
```

using the below code to do docker build which is not working

```
      - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
        displayName: 'Authenticate to Artifacts'
        inputs:
          nuGetServiceConnections: 'ServiceName'

      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: 'Build image'
        inputs:
          command: 'build' 
          Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
          arguments: '--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)'
```

I have tried to debug the issue by adding --verbosity detailed to dotnet restore and found that and i am getting the following message in pipeline

[CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - IsRetry: True
[CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json
[CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 0
[CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 0
1>/src/directory/Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json.

I am not sure why after Found credentials for endpoint i am getting error Unable to load the service index for source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing Nuget restore and build with dotnet cli and copying the build files to docker. The NuGetAuthenticate@1 task does work outside docker.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! Glad to know it's resolved. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed your dockerfile and yaml, confirm it's working on my side.

[image]

Here are some steps and considerations to help you troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

1. Check the value of `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` value in the log, it should the correct feed url, and credential.
   [image]
2. Check on target feed setting, make sure the user has contributor role or above.
3. Verify the Token `$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)`, make sure it's working, you can recreate it for a check.
4. Check NuGet.config, make sure it's correctly referencing the private feed.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have already verified all 4 points that you have mentioned still not working I solved the issue by doing Nuget restore and build with dotnet and copying the build files to docker